# Does anyone know if/where Univers font is hosted as web font?

Tags: fonts

I've checked Typekit and Fontsquirrel, but I haven't found a webfont hosting service that carries Univers.  If anyone knows of one, please pass that information along.

If you have another suggestion as to how I might legally host Univers as a webfont, I'd welcome that too.  For example, if you know of a font store that sells Univers along with the specific privilege of using as a webfont.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the answer below still stands, but to my knowledge you still can't host Univers and serve it as a font via CSS **legally**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Univers is a Linotype typeface, available through their parent company, Monotype, on fonts.com